# django db lookup for datetime

Tags: database, datetime, django-models, filter

I'm trying to filter database entries by their datetime:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class ContestEvent(models.Model):
    year = models.DateTimeField()
    month = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my view I define a function calender:

```
def calendar(request, pYear, pMonth):
    """
    Show calendar of events for specified month and year
    """
    lYear = int(pYear)
    lMonth = int(pMonth)
    lCalendarFromMonth = datetime(lYear, lMonth, 1)
    lCalendarToMonth = datetime(lYear, lMonth, monthrange(lYear, lMonth)[1])
    my_workouts = ContestEvent.objects.filter(id__year=lCalendarFromMonth, id__month=lCalendarToMonth)
    lCalendar = html_calendar.WorkoutCalendar(my_workouts).formatmonth(lYear, lMonth)
```

Then I got the following error:

```
Request Method:   GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/htmlcalendar/
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Exception Location:  C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_db_prep_lookup, line 225
```

The error is the same, when I define my Model with `year = models.IntegerField()` instead of `year = models.DateTimeField()`

What is wrong here. I'm a Django Beginner.
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say if you want the month and year then use IntegerField, and when you do that you no longer need to create datetime objects to pass to your filter.  Try something like this:

```
class ContestEvent(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.IntegerField()

def calendar(request, pYear, pMonth):
    """
    Show calendar of events for specified month and year
    """
    lYear = int(pYear)
    lMonth = int(pMonth)
    my_workouts = ContestEvent.objects.filter(year=lYear, month=lMonth)
```